# Best way to perform a subquery in Ruby + Rails when getting an average?

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, subquery

Trying to get this query using ActiveRecord, how would I write it properly?

```sql
SELECT AVG(IF(condition)) AS average_id 
FROM (SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `id` = 1 
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 10) `table`;
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Uri! Wasn't sure on how to format the SQL :P

Answer (score 0):

Given that `table` is modeled by a model named `MyModel` - the above would be translated roughly to this:

```
MyModel.average('IF(condition)').where(id: 1).order(date: :desc).limit(10)
```